How to implement Three.js into my snippet
I have a question about Three.js, but I don't know how to implement Three.js code through a snippet. I can't do an import, but I did notice that you can add an external library. I'm new to these things, so I want to make sure I use them correctly. What should I type in to the prompt box to make Three.js work in a snippet?

We generally don't require snippets to run in-browser here. Just showing the relevant code and an image, video, or animated gif of what the result looks like / how it differs from what you want usually suffices. So, don't feel like you must solve this problem before posting your question. A good visual example is usually enough for a question to be well-received here.

I can do a gif. I guess I'll show my javascript code in the snippet just for some clarification (Cause there is a lot). That should be good, correct?

That sounds good to me. I think it's worth keeping this Meta question open, as embedding three.js here would indeed be awesome and good for users to know about. I'm just not sure how or if it's even possible, so I don't want to block you from getting help with your original problem in the meantime.

You need to enter a publicly available URL to your three.js (or whatever.js) file.
But fear not, in 2024 (and beyond), you're in luck!
At the time I'm writing this, there are services available that provide JavaScript libraries: for instance, I type three.js cdn in DuckDuckGo and I get a link to cdnjs which describes itself like this:

cdnjs is a free and open-source CDN service trusted by over 12.5% of all websites, serving over 200 billion requests each month, powered by Cloudflare.
We make it faster and easier to load library files on your websites.

I'm not promoting this service exactly but you get the point.
When you get to the actual page given by DDG, you land here, which proposes actual publicly available URLs to three.js files of different versions.
I'm not familiar with three.js exactly, but the idea is that you copy the URLs from there into the text box you described in the Question; you do that for each URL. You'll then see appear the URL in the HTML section of the code snippet UI in a script tag.
I haven't worked with this lately so the exact way this works is fuzzy a bit, but AFAIR, you should be good to go!

This appears like the proposed approach to work with JavaScript file. Buuuuttt.... like everything "external link", this may be subject to link rot. No one knows if/when the service will come down (that is, before StackExchange). Maybe another approach is to copy/paste the whole content of the external JavaScript into the script section of the script tag. This, however, may be subject to characters limit.
As a moderator, however, using URLs to publicly available JS files in this situation is a non-issue for me, if we get to the point where the URL rots, we'll just go ahead and fix them all (I don't think there will be a lot).

Disclaimer: my HTML/JS is a bit rusty, so things in here may be inaccurate, so anyone reading this, you're welcome to bring any fix that it requires.
